# Horizontal axis not working after animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So, I have built a simple car game, and have attached a script that allows it to move on both axes. I have created an animation, so that if the car turns upside down, there is an option to press the 'f' button and flip the car back to normal. Unfortunately, once the animation plays and the car flips back onto it's wheels, the car moves forwards and backwards, but doesn't rotate.

What could be the issue?

Here is the script:

```
var speed : float = 10.0;
var rotationSpeed : float = 100.0;
var CarFlip : Animator;

function Start () {
CarFlip.enabled = false;
}

function Update () {
var translation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;
var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
translation *= Time.deltaTime;
rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate (0, 0, translation);
transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F)){
    CarFlip.enabled = true;
}
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B)){
            speed = 30;
        }
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.B)){
            speed = 15;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use [car] tag. _"`car` refers to the `car` package under the R language, NOT to drivable cars"_

Answer (score 1):

The Animator updates the transforms every frame so your change in Update() is being over-written.

If you want to override what it has done you need to apply your changes during LateUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

I think the animator is still enabled making the rotation stuck. Maybe try something like this as a test to see if setting animator to false will get the car rotating again:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
{
   CarFlip.enabled = true;
}
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
{
   CarFlip.enabled = false;
}
```